# sending an email from an forms Application (why dosen't it work)

Tags: email, gmail, system.net.mail

[image]I am trying to learn how to send a simple email with c# visual studio forms Application. (it could also be a console application for all I care). Here is the code I have(I don't see what's wrong with the code, it should work right?):

```
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("(here is my email)");
            mail.To.Add("(here is my email)");
            mail.Subject = "toja";
            mail.Body = "ja";

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("(here is my email)", "(here is my password)");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
            MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: How do you know it did not work? What is the error?

Comment: I can't show you the whole eror cause I can't coppy it but here is the begining few lines: "System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server rewuires a secure connection or the client was not authuenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication "

Comment: From this [page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en), If you tried configuring your SMTP server on port 465 (with SSL/TLS) and port 587 (with STARTTLS), but are still having trouble sending mail, try configuring your SMTP to use port 25 (with SSL/TLS).

Comment: You should probably try standard port 25 as per the doc.

Comment: I've tried setting the port both to 25 and 465 but it still dose not work.

Comment: what is the error after you use port 25?

Comment: the error is: "Şystem.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail.--->"System.Net.webException:unable to connect to the remote server.--->" and a bunch more shoul I get you the whole error? it has probably 200 words.

Comment: Edit the question and add the details there.

Comment: Hey I've added a screenshot of the error when the port is 587.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following to send email from C# Forms application and it works.
Maybe you should try adding the smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false property and set the Credentials property?

```
// Create our new mail message
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add("toAddress");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("fromAddress");
mailMessage.Subject = "subject";
mailMessage.Body = "body";

// Set the IsBodyHTML option if it is HTML email
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

// Enter SMTP client information
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("mail.server.address");
NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
```

If using Gmail you can find the SMTP server information here https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en.  It looks like the address is `smtp.gmail.com` and the port is `465` for SSL or `587` for TLS.  I would suggest you try using default port 25 first to make sure your email goes through, then adjust to a different port if you need to.

Comment: I've tried using your code and the both "NetworkCredentials" in this line:NetworkCredential basicCredential = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");  are an error how do I do this again? I feel like i'm missing something very obvius and that's what bothers me so much .

Comment: You probably need the following imports... using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;

Comment: When I click the button an error apers. I think it has something to do with the port. What port should I use?

Comment: @bananalord what does the error say?  Can you paste it into a pastebin?

Comment: here is a screenshot with the whole code and the error(I think that my problem is that in "mail.server.address" I put the port right?)            https://gyazo.com/85d63a324d2822bd4b7f13ca49f04b65

Comment: @bananalord, where you have ...new SmtpClient("587") change it to new SmtpClient("mail.server.address", 587);

Comment: I have no idea what i'm doing wrong.Im starting to lose my minde at this point here is what the error says, it still doesn't work:  https://gyazo.com/9471d1abe6003c64ef229e2b5a3a0ace

Comment: @bananalord you can't use mail.server.address, that was just an EXAMPLE.  you need to replace that text with your ACTUAL SMTP MAIL SERVER ADDRESS.

Comment: I am so sorry I'm getting paranoid I planed to get this email thing done in 30 mins and then continue to the next step in my program.

Comment: wait how do I get "mail.server.address" at first I thout It's gmail.com (I'm so sorry by the way I bet you are getting anoid by me)

Comment: @bananalord I've updated my answer to provide you with the Gmail SMTP server address and port information.

Comment: I have figures out what was wrong both your code and mine were right.The problem was then in 2016 google addad a feture that makes the gmail not able to be used in suspicious software. I just needed to disable it  that's also why the code worked for me over a year ago.

Comment: @bananalord glad you figured it out :)